# Which RMarkdown theme/style is used to get the TOC shown below?

Tags: r-markdown

The default floating table-of-contents looks like below using theme 'united' I think.

[image]

How does one create the TOC theme/style shown below?

[image]

Here is the [page](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/install.html).

Here is another example:

[image]

Link [here](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle-release/docs/).

This question is not about how to create the floating TOC or about the general page style/theme, but where does the specific TOC style come from? Is it an argument somewhere? Perhaps some variation to tocify?

Answer (score 0):

html_document output supports TOC, you just need to turn it on. 
Try this:

```
---
title: "example yaml"
author: "you"
date: "8/20/2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---
```

More settings of TOC, please refer to [Rmarkdown: the definitive guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html)

Edit:

I checked the [gh-page](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/tree/gh-pages) for your link, however I didn't know how the author generated those pages. If you want the same appearance of TOC in that page, maybe ask the author?

Comment: Updated the question. Just thought that asking several hundred users here might be more effective. But maybe you are right, I should just ask the author.